# Asp.net Core 3.0 CORS not working based on official documentation

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, cors

I want to enable CORS with Asp.Net Core 3.0 API project. This is the basic generated Asp.Net Core Api template. Everything is default from the template, except I added CORS settings from the documentation: [Enable Cross-Origin Requests (CORS) in ASP.NET Core](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/cors?view=aspnetcore-3.0)

Here it is my Startup.cs

```
public class Startup
{
        public Startup(IConfiguration configuration)
        {
            Configuration = configuration;
        }

        public IConfiguration Configuration { get; }

        // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to add services to the container.
        public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
        {
            services.AddControllers();
            services.AddCors(options =>
            {
                options.AddPolicy("CorsPolicy",
                    builder => builder.WithOrigins("localhost", "www.google.com")
                    .AllowAnyMethod()
                    .AllowAnyHeader()
                    .AllowCredentials());
            });
        }

        // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to configure the HTTP request pipeline.
        public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IWebHostEnvironment env)
        {
            if (env.IsDevelopment())
            {
                app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
            }

            app.UseHttpsRedirection();

            app.UseRouting();

            app.UseCors("CorsPolicy");
            app.UseAuthorization();

            app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
            {
                endpoints.MapControllers();
            });
        }
  }
```

And these are my response headers:
[image]

What should I set up for getting corret CORS headers in Response?

Here it is my fetch api test:
[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Oops, I successed to solve this.

This combination was the only one to me, what is working:

```
public class Startup
{
        public Startup(IConfiguration configuration)
        {
            Configuration = configuration;
        }

        public IConfiguration Configuration { get; }

        // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to add services to the container.
        public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
        {
            services.AddControllers();
            services.AddCors(); //This needs to let it default
        }

        // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to configure the HTTP request pipeline.
        public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IWebHostEnvironment env)
        {
            if (env.IsDevelopment())
            {
                app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
            }

            app.UseHttpsRedirection();

            app.UseRouting();

            app.UseCors(
                options => options.SetIsOriginAllowed(x => _ = true).AllowAnyMethod().AllowAnyHeader().AllowCredentials()
            ); //This needs to set everything allowed

            app.UseAuthorization();

            app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
            {
                endpoints.MapControllers();
            });
        }
}
```

Comment: Thank you, bro, had the same problem !

Comment: Thank you, however the piece with origin should be `SetIsOriginAllowed(_ => true)` (the effect is the same, but dummy assignment makes no sense).

Answer (score 0):

If you put the API URL directly in the browser, CORS is not involved.
It isn't a cross-origin request.

That only happens when you have a page hosted at one origin, e.g. localhost:5000, which has JavaScript code that calls an API at origin localhost:5001.
(or otherwise fetches resources from another origin)

But in your case the only origin is the API origin and thus CORS is not needed.

Comment: I tested it also with fetch api, with the same result (no cors headers). My original issue extended with fetch api screenshot.

Comment: Simple requests may not trigger a CORS preflight.

Comment: Your CORS configuration cannot give your site access to Google.  You have it backwards.  *Google* needs to add *your site* to their CORS configuration to give you access.

Comment: @Amy it is a fetch from origin www.google.com to localhost. Of course it is OP's CORS that matters. If the call was going to a Google API, then it would be theirs.

Comment: @Amy no it is not google's side setting, it is my side's setting, and it seems Asp.Net Core 3.0 CORS settings not working :(